# How to solve npm install errors on Mac

Tags: npm-install

I purchased a template online for a Gatsby JS website and when I tried to use it, it worked, but then it just stopped. I tried opening the project in a new directory and it failed.

Currently I am unable to run `npm install` for the project and have no idea how to solve the issue.

The error messages are:

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/sharp
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
    npm ERR! info sharp Using cached /Users/chistopherholder/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.10.0-darwin-x64.tar.br
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.5 | darwin | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chistopherholder/.node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/chistopherholder/.node-gyp/14.15.5',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/chistopherholder/.node-gyp/14.15.5/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/sharp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/chistopherholder/Desktop/react_play/rewy-gatsby-with-strapi/rewy-api/node_modules/sharp
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.5
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/chistopherholder/.npm/_logs/2021-03-05T00_04_39_680Z-debug.log
```

I opened up the debug.log but it is a 1787 lines of code that I don't quite understand.
I also tried `sudo npm install`.

How can I solve these issues?

Any hint in the right direction would be much appreciated. I am usually working with django and not react so I am a bit clueless here.

Comment: "No Xcode or CLT version detected" - have you already tried installing xcode?

Comment: Isn't Xcode a code editor? No I do not remember doing that. Would it help? I mainly do web atm

Comment: xcode includes compilers and development libraries needed to compile code on a mac. You may be confusing it with vscode, which is an IDE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may not be the same issue in every case, but whenever I see the `npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!` I have to remove xcode and reinstall, then the error goes away.  My best guess is that it's an issue with Node and/or MacOs updates that cause conflicts.

When this happens you can first try:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

And if that doesn't work (which it never has for me) you can then try:

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path) && xcode-select --install
```

Comment: that second one worked for me

Comment: The easiest solution is still to login in AppStore then install or update Xcode .

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be like the correct way of fixing it but I would love to have someone explain a better way to fix this type of issues.

Basically I uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs with brew.

```
brew uninstall node
brew install node
brew cleanup
```

Rean

```
npm install -g npm
```

Then reset the project back to the beginning and restarted my computer.

Now it works but I don't understand what went wrong and i'm sure I will run into the issue again.

Maybe I should be running this in a Pipenv shell